# Problem about passing an array in struct when using pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct, pthreads

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/* You may need to define struct here */
struct arg_type {
    int head;
    int length;
    int num;
    float *vec;
    double *sqsum;
};

/*!
 * \brief subroutine function
 *
 * \param arg, input arguments pointer
 * \return void*, return pointer
 */
void *l2_norm(void *arg) { 
    /* TODO: Your code here */
    struct arg_type *a = (struct arg_type *)arg;
    a->sqsum[a->num] = 0.0f;
    for (int j = a->head; j < (a->head + a->length); j++) {
        a->sqsum[a->num] += a->vec[j] * a->vec[j];
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*!
 * \brief wrapper function
 *
 * \param vec, input vector array
 * \param len, length of vector
 * \param k, number of threads
 * \return float, l2 norm
 */
float multi_thread_l2_norm(const float *vec, size_t len, int k) { 
    /* TODO: your code here */
    double sum = 0.0f;
    struct arg_type arg;
    pthread_t tid;
    
    *arg.vec = *vec;
    
    arg.length = (int)len / k;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        arg.num = i;
        arg.head = arg.length * i;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, l2_norm, &arg);
    }
    
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        sum += arg.sqsum[j];
    }
    sum = sqrt(sum);
    return sum;
}
```

I am a beginner and new to this topic.

This is a program to calculate L2 norm using multiple threads and compare the time with the naive implementation.

After using GDB, I am pretty sure that the program stuck on line 49.

`*arg.vec = *vec;`

But I am not sure why and struggling to debug it

Comment: The code above is part of the code which is relevant to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arg.vec is a pointer which is not allocated so accessing the content would crash.

Should be,

arg.vec = vec ;

Beside, other probems in the code are --

1. Need array of arg:
   You created 'k' number of threads, but you are passing same 'arg' structure to every thread, so the variable members(i.e. num, head) of 'arg' might be same inside the thread functions based on concurrent run.
   Hence, you need 'k' number of structure of 'arg' i.e. array of arg structure and passing each element of it to each thread.
2. Need array tid:
   Also, You created 'k' number of threads, but you did join only for one thread(i.e the last thread) i.e. you are ensuring only last thread to be finished. To ensure, all threads to be finished, you need to wait for all threads those are created.

Comment: Turns out we still need to change the function signature to `float multi_thread_l2_norm (float *vec, size_t len, int k)`

Comment: Since arg.vec member in structure you declared as non-constant, so assigning it to incoming vec ( a const) would give error. And since you are not changing content of vec in your function , so const would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing the arg variable  where you should give each thread its copy

```
// you need to allocate new memory zone before storing the vec in it
// ex : arg = malloc(sizeof(arg_type ));
*arg.vec = *vec;
```

in your case all thread will have the same arg.num, arg.head ...